# How to change '.' into a '/' for called routes?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to replace a `.` by  `/` in my called routes.

For example, in my proto, I want to be able to click on the image of a post to go on the show page. But now, the route which is called with the id has this form:

```
push.88
```

And I want to have this form:

```
push/88
```

My code is:

Route:

```
get 'push/:id/', to: 'pushs#show'
```

Views/pushs/index:

```
<%- @pushs.each do |push| %>



      <div class="image text-center">
        <div class="image-border">
          <%=l ink_to (image_tag push.post.image.url(:medium), class: 'img-responsive'), push_path(push[:id])%>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The Push controller is:

```
class PushsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_push, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def new 
  end 

  def index
    @pushs = Push.all.reverse
    @users = User.all


  end 

  def show 

  end 



  def create 
    @push = @post.pushs.create(push_params)

    if @push.save
      flash[:success] = 'Votre commande est enregisté !'
      redirect_to root_path 
    else    
      flash[:alert] = "Check the push form, something went horribly wrong."
      redirect_to root_path 
    end 
  end 

  def update
    if @push.update(push_params)
      @push.update(user_id: current_user.id)
      @push.update(prix2: @post.prix)
      flash[:success] = 'Votre commande est enregistré !'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Check the push form, something went horribly wrong."
      render 'edit'
    end 
  end

  def destroy  
  @push = @post.pushs.find(params[:id])
  @push.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Push deleted :("
  redirect_to root_path
end  


private

  def push_params
    params.require(:push).permit(:user_id, :quantity, :prix2, :time, :adress2, :latitude2, :longitude2, :taked, :taked_by, :taked_at, :validated)
  end 


  def set_post  
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end  


  def set_push
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @push = @post.pushs.find(params[:id]) 
  end 



end
```

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript ? It seems to be entirely Rails.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking or answering, please don't use salutations, valedictions, or signatures. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion board, instead we're working on an online reference book.

Comment: @the Tin Man, oh OK, i understand better now, well thks for editing me

Comment: When you do, `rake routes` what's the prefix for `'push/:id/'` route?

Comment: +1@Kumar Abinash   Well, thanks to this question, I find the problem. It's because I have to integreate the post id to use this routes, like this : get 'post/:id/push/:id/', to: 'pushs#show'   & and rewrite my code accordingly to call the two factors like this : post_push_path(push.post_id, push).